# How can I change this "Killer Resolution" to normal resolution?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, resolution, reinstall

I wanted to reinstall Windows 10 the other night and it completed. Next day I went on the computer and noticed that the resolution was low so I went in and changed that to the highest, I don't remember what resolution it was but it was something like 1200x(three numbers). It was pretty low resolution still so I clicked on it, and almost everything went black. Only like 1 centimeter at the top was visible. I restarted it like 3-5 times but nothing changed. I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to login and navigate with TAB thru all the steps to reinstall Windows 10 again?

or

2. Can I login and navigate with TAB to change the resolution?

If I can do something like that, please give me a guide on where to go (well, I know where to go, but not without a screen).
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: you should be able to boot into safemode and re-install your graphics device from there.  This SHOULD clear any bad configuration and restore your configuration to default when you restart the machine.  I've done this one windows 7 but not on windows 10.

Safemode can be entered with F8 when booting.

Comment: Thank you for the help but now when I started the PC it of course decided to fix it by itself :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was fixed by a restart.

Comment: Ok do that, but it wasn't fixed after a restart, it was fixed after the night.  Bye.